# could I know which file is altered using fsevent?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I get the directory path from fsevent, such as "/User/Data/"
But what I really want is "/User/Data/change.txt"
I have read the programming guide, it said

```
typedef void ( *FSEventStreamCallback )(
    ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
    void *clientCallBackInfo,
    size_t numEvents,
    void *eventPaths,
    const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
    const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[]);
```

> eventPaths An array of paths to the
>   directories in which event(s)
>   occurred.

is there any method to find out which file is altered?
thanks!!!! 
I have stuck to it for so long..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is kqueue.  See Appendix A of the "File System Events Programming Guide".

Comment: use kqueue only if you want to watch for very limited number of files.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your usage needs, you might consider low level fsevents.  The process must run as root.  Here is a [simple example](https://web.archive.org/web/20180924040312/http://osxbook.com/software/fslogger/download/fslogger.c) of reading from `/dev/fsevents` instead of using the FSEvents wrappers.  With this you will get the full path as well as the process making the change and other details.

Comment: fslogger seems working till snowleopard only. When it try to clone the /dev/fsevents using ioctl, ioctl returns error num : 14 (Bad Address). Any idea how to fix it ..?

Answer (score 1):

In 10.7+ you can pass the kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents flag to FSEventStreamCreate for individual file information. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSEventStreamCreate).